# TWO MySQL commands (SELECT to View), but only one is showing output

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, command

I have a table and each , I want to select a data from the same table in my database.

For example, first <**td**> is first name, then the second <**td**> is phone number.

I got the command, but only the first command is showing output.

This is my *php* codes to open and connect to the database :

```
<?php
  include("./inc/db_connect.php");

  $conn = OpenCon();
?>
```

This is the *php* codes for the table including <**th**> and <**td**> :

```
<div class="layer55">
  <h3>
    <table class="flat-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <?php
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM sharp_emp WHERE employee_id = 'AA170336'";

              if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  echo "Name";
                }
              }
            ?>
          </th>

          <th>
            <?php
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM sharp_emp WHERE employee_id = 'AA170336'";

              if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  echo "Phone Number";
                }
              }
            ?>
          </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php
              $sql = "SELECT first_name FROM sharp_emp WHERE employee_id = 'AA170336'";

              while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                echo "" . $row['first_name'] . "";
              }
            ?>
          </td>

          <td>
            <?php
              $sql = "SELECT phone FROM sharp_emp WHERE employee_id = 'AA170336'";

              while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                echo "" . $row['phone'] . "";
              }
            ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </h3>
</div>
```

This is the *php* codes for **db_connect.php** :

```
<?php
  function OpenCon()
  {
   $dbhost = "localhost";
   $dbuser = // Hidden;
   $dbpass = // Hidden;
   $db = "sharp_db";
   $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);

   return $conn;
  }

  function CloseCon($conn)
  {
   $conn -> close();
  }
?>
```

The expected output :

```
|----------|----------|    
|Name      |Phone Number|    
|----------|----------|    
|John      |179898765 |
```

The current output :

```
|----------|----------|
|Name      |Phone Number|
|----------|----------|
|John      |Null (empty) |
```

Comment: You are ReUsing the varibale `$result` on both the `->query()` calls. so the second destroys the resultset created by the first :)

Comment: Why run the same query 4 times?

Comment: So I have to differentiate those `$result` ? maybe `$result1` , `$result2` , `$result3` , `$result4`

@RiggsFolly
@user3783243

Comment: btw, I'm talking about <td> tags, not <th> tags.

Those <th> tags, are successful but the <td> tags aren't.

"Name" and "Phone Number" are showing despite using the same commands, but "John" is the only one showing for "Name" and empty for "Phone Number", why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the same query multiple times, overwriting the `$result` variable for no reason, having useless `$sql` for the later 2 fetch without using them, and fetching a single `$result` twice by mistake.

So there are multiple concept problem with your code. I think your current code is something equivalant to this:

```php
<div class="layer55">
  <h3>
    <table class="flat-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM sharp_emp WHERE employee_id = 'AA170336'";
            if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
              if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          ?>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <?php if ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>
            <td><?php echo "" . $row['first_name'] . ""; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "" . $row['phone'] . ""; ?></td>
          <?php } else { ?>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          <?php } ?>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </h3>
</div>
```

But frankly, it makes no sense to me to print an empty table when there is no result. So what you need is probably something like this.

```php
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sharp_emp WHERE employee_id = 'AA170336'";
if (
  ($result = $conn->query($sql))
  && ($result->num_rows > 0)
  && ($row = $result->fetch_array())
):

?>
<div class="layer55">
  <h3>
    <table class="flat-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </h3>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `$result1` and `$result2` are the same. It would be better to just have 1 result set.

Comment: Checking and changing my answer, hold on xD

Comment: @hycarlDev_: Changed my answer. Please check.

Comment: @KoalaYeung , your answer is correct, got it already but had to change one minor mistake, `&& ($row = $result1->fetch_array())`, it should be `$result` instead of `$result1` but overall, problems solved, thanks!